# Gravitational redshift discrepancy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-redshift

I want to compute the redshift of a signal emitted by a static observer in $r=R_1$, $\phi=\phi_1$and recieved by another static observ at $r=R_2$, $\phi=\phi_2$ with $R_2>R_1$, in Schwarzschild metric.
So i determined it in two different manners obtaing different results.
First i considered the metric for a static observer

$$ds^2=-(1-\frac{2m}{r})dt^2=-d\tau^2$$
$$dt=\frac{d\tau_1}{(1-\frac{2m}{R_1})^{1/2}}=\frac{d\tau_2}{(1-\frac{2m}{R_2})^{1/2}}$$
So results

$$\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda}=\frac{(1-\frac{2m}{R_2})^{1/2}}{(1-\frac{2m}{R_1})^{1/2}}$$

Instead using the simmetry under timereversal of the metric we have

$$\frac{dt}{d\tau}(1-\frac{2m}{r})=constant$$
$$dt=\frac{d\tau_1}{(1-\frac{2m}{R_1})}=\frac{d\tau_2}{(1-\frac{2m}{R_2})}$$

Giving

$$\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda}=\frac{(1-\frac{2m}{R_2})}{(1-\frac{2m}{R_1})}$$
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The expression
$$\left( 1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \frac{E}{mc^2} = {\rm constant}$$
would apply to an inertial observer in the Schwarzschild metric. i.e. The $\tau$ here corresponds to the proper time experienced by an inertial (free-falling) observer.

Your first expression
$$ \left( 1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{1/2}dt = d\tau$$
would apply in a case where $dr = d\phi=0$, i.e. the case where $\tau$ is the proper time experienced by a stationary, and therefore non-inertial observer.

Answer (score 0):

Stationary observer
The procedure for the gravitational redshift is correct.

Time independence of the metric
The time independence of Schwarzschild allows for the energy as a conserved quantity. However it is defined for a geodesic. It is not applicable to a stationary observer.

Comment: But should not a stationary observer still have the time indipendece? The metric for it (first equation)  seems recover the invariance under time-reversal and so the conservation of energy.

Comment: The energy as a conserved quantity is given by the inner product of the time Killing vector and the momentum applied to a geodesic, i.e. to a particle in free fall. A stationary observer is not following a geodesic, so it is not applicable.

Comment: So maybe i misunderstood the text: A static observer at r = R1, θ = π/2, φ = φ1 in Schwarzschild spacetime sends a light signal
with wavelength λ towards another static observer at r = R2 > R1, θ = π/2, φ = φ2. Compute
the wavelength measured by the second observer (using energy conservation along geodesic
motion).
It says eplicitly to use energy conservation

Comment: The energy conservation allows to express the energy (frequency) of a free falling photon vs. the energy at infinity (far away from the massive object) in Schwarzschild coordinates. However that is not the energy (frequency) measured by a stationary observer. Reason is the time dilation between Schwarzschild coordinates and a stationary observer.